# Understanding some concepts and Hazelcast Jet integrated with Kafka

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I'm trying to map some concepts between Spark Structured Streaming and Hazelcast Jet, and understand another subjects as well.

Q1 - In the Spark, each Kafka partition will become a partition inside spark, then they will be processed by individual tasks in parallel. I think that I've read somewhere that Hazelcast Jet will merge all the messages from kafka regardless the group.id and topic partitions, is that correct ?

Q2 - How do we grow the number of "consumers" in a Jet program to increase the throughput consuming from kafka ? In Spark I guess we only need to grow the number of topic partitions in order to a new spark task be assigned for the new partition.

Q3 - If the Q1 above is true, is it possible avoid that merge and distribute the kafka partitions to be processed in parallel ? Once the messages will be already grouped and ordered in a kafka partition, having all the messages merged imply extra processing to re-partition and sort the messages again.

Q4 - How is defined the number of each vertex ? I mean, in the word count example we have the tokenizer and accumulator, how Jet will decide/divide the number of processors to creates instances of tokenizer's and accumulator's ?

Answer (score 1):

A1 - The number of parallel processors is totally independent from the number of Kafka partitions. The number of processors is determined by [local parallelism](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.5.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/jet/core/Vertex.html#localParallelism-int-) of the vertex and the number of members:

```
totalParallelism = numberOfMembers * localParallelism
```

Each processor will be assigned a subset of all topic-partitions and uses one `KafkaConsumer`. `group.id` is not used, Jet uses manual partition assignment.

A2 - Adding new partitions to Kafka topic doesn't increase the number of consumers. You need to increase the local parallelism.

A3 - There's no extra cost of "merging" and "sorting". You might want to have a look [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.5.1/manual/Under_the_Hood/How_Distributed_Computing_Works_in_Jet.html). Basically each vertex is backed by multiple parallel processors and each edge is backed by multiple queues, one queue for each two processors. If downstream processor takes items from multiple queues, it just does so queue by queue; there's no extra cost for merging. There's also no sorting in the sense that items are reordered. If the edge is not [distributed](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.5.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/jet/core/Edge.html#distributed--), all processing is local and nothing is serialized.

Answer is valid for Jet 0.5.1 and 0.6 (which is in development at the time of writing).

A4 - see A1.

Comment: Thanks @Oliv . In a long running application, such as an infinite streaming consumer, is it possible to redefine (increase or reduce) on-the-fly the number of parallel vertex's (totalParallelism = numberOfMembers * localParallelism) ? I mean, in case joining new members in the cluster could I redefine the parallelism of my application without shutdown and starting it again ?

Comment: Since local parallelism is set according to the number of CPU cores, there is no gain in increasing it.

Comment: @KleysonRios No, it's not possible. The parallelism can only be changed when the job is restarted. However, Jet 0.5 (and probably 0.6 also) does not have an API to restart the job manually. You can only cancel the job, but you will lose the state.

Comment: @Oliv this is a kind odd in the sense that I can join new nodes in the cluster but my application cannot scale out without stopping it, loosing all the states and starting it again. How the Jet customers deal with this need ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree that increasing localParallelism won't have any gain in performance, but increasing the "numberOfMembers" does.

Comment: @KleysonRios autoscaling up when new nodes are added in either 0.6 or 0.7 release. Until then, you can cancel and resubmit the job manually.